# Caso haja espaços nas pastas ou imagens, como se resolve?

Tags: html, aplicação-web

No caso eu estou aprendendo WEB(HTML,php,Css e Javascript), e para html existe a função de por imagens, porém eu me deparei com a dificuldade de enviar uma imagem se ela tiver espaços no nome ou no caminho.

```
 <body>
 <img src="../../pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg" width="400" height="300">
 </body>
```

Eu sei que é recomendado não utilizar espaços para linguagens de programação e etc, mas eu queria saber se existe uma forma de resolver isso sem renomear pastas ou arquivos, só por conhecimento mesmo, pq de fato tenho o costume de não utilizar espaços.
Alguém sabe como resolver isto, ou só renomeando msm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode trocar os espaços pelo código ASCII correspondente precedido por `%`. o código ficaria algo como:

```
 <body>
     <img src="../../pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Desert.jpg" width="400" height="300">
 </body>
```

Só reforçando que esse não é o recomendável, como você mesmo apontou.

Comment: Beleza, deu para entender a ideia.